# Ubuntu VM doesn't recognize expanded storage in hard drive

Tags: virtualbox, hard-drive, 14.10

I just expanded the storage of my hard drive for my Ubuntu VM on VirtualBox from my Macbook Air terminal but I don't think the VM has realized that. I got a message saying `Not enough free disk space: The upgrade needs a total of 602 M free space on disk '/'`. I think this is a Ubuntu problem not a Macbook problem. I'm kind of confused on what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You just increased the capacity of the physical file (or virtual disk), you still need to modify the partition table contained inside the virtual disk.

You'll need to mount the ISO file used for the installation on your VirtualBox. Start a live session and execute [GParted](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/)

It should be fairly easy with the graphical interface. If for any reason GParted is not installed, open a terminal and execute

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

WARNING!!!! You there's a risk of loosing data. You may want to backup important things.
Although is pretty safe most of the time.

Finally reboot!

Comment: I'm using gparted but I can't resize my partition. The system isn't letting me. When I typed in the amount I wanted it expanded to, it goes back to the current size of the partition. I also can't move the bar or arrow on top of my resizing screen.

Comment: Please attach screenshots of your current size, and the size you want to have. Although it could be easier/faster just to have a clean install, unless you have a lot of data to backup.

Comment: I don't know how to take a screenshot of my VM. Also, a clean install isn't feasible as I have projects on VM I would rather not delete.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sdaX
$ df -h
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I expanded the HD and erased all previous snapshots, this solved the problem.

According to https://askubuntu.com/a/773193/452891, one can change the size also for the snapshots using console OracleVM apps (`VBoxManage list hdds` and `VBoxManage modifyhd`), and this should also solve the problem, but I didn't try myself.