# Guest system does not see the updated disk size in VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, virtualbox, gparted, virtualization

In the last time on every start of my Ubuntu 14.04 VM I'm getting the message

> **Low Disk Space**
>
> This computer has only 314.8 MB disk space remaining. You may free up some space by emptying the trash.

[image]

Now I've increased the disk space from `10` to `20 GB` as described on the [VirtualBox forum](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=50661) (first step).

```
M:\>"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" modifyhd "M:\VM\Ubuntu VM\Ubuntu VM.vdi" --resize 20480
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
```

I see, that the disk space has been resized successfully:

[image]

But when I start the machine and open GParted, only `10 GB` are available.

[image]

So somehow the Ubuntu guest system haven't got the updated information about the disk space.

**How to solve it and complete the disk space increase?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally found the solution [here](http://www.ceus-now.com/gparted-doesn-t-recognize-my-newly-resized-vdi/):

View all of the drives associated with VirtualBox

```
$ "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" list hdds
```

For each associated drive use `modifyhd`:

```
$ "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage" modifyhd "D:\Pat\to\VM\Snapshots\{b0e3f93f-49fe-49bc-9ae2-79e80da6cf01}.vdi" --resize 20480
```

Now GParted sees the added space.

NOTE: The curly braced snapshot entries require the last forward slash to be changed to a backslash. Meaning:

```
...\Snapshots\{...}.vdi
```

instead of

```
...\Snapshots/{...}.vdi
```

Comment: I had to do this with both the main VDI and the Snapshot in Snapshots/ for this to work. I did just the snapshot first and fdisk showed the larger partition but pvcreate threw an error "Fatal error while trying to detect swap signature on /dev/sda3" I also only had one snapshot so you may need to either do it with the latest snapshot or all of them? ive not tested this but its working now

Comment: There is nothing in my `Snapshots` folder.

Comment: @Timoth use the virtual midia manager to locate the snapshots.

Comment: Spot on! My problem was that I didn't run the script for the Snapshots too.

Comment: This does not do the trick with version 6.06 of VirtualBox unfortunately. Ubuntu does not see the increases.

Comment: Likewise, I had to modifyhd in the /Snapshots dir as well and worked. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 10):

1) Open GParted tool

2) In the graphical interface you'll see existing partitions and an unallocated partition

3)Click the partition you would like to extend

4) In the top action bar you'll see an arrow directed right. Click it and you'll get option to extend the partition with the unallocated space

Answer (score 3):

Try installing scsitools and re-scanning the devices

```
sudo apt-get install scsitools

sudo rescan-scsi-bus.sh
```

Then check the available space

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Or use gparted if that's what you prefer.
If you see the extra space extend the partition

And lastly extend the filesystem on the guest vm

```
resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried it, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a Ubuntu virtual machine.
First, I powered off the machine. Then, **I removed saved states**, which are probably the reason why the virtual machine couldn't see the resized disk. Just to be sure, I updated the virtual space once more and started the virtual machine. Now, I can finally see the unallocated space.

Answer (score 1):

I have nearly had the same problem and overall was frustated. In my case it was nearly like @Ladislav Ondris.

I saved my Snapshots, but missed to log out and shut down the VM in the last Snapshot. So gparted did not show anything free to resize.

After shutdown, and making a new Snapshot. I could open gparted and he showed in the right corner the bigger disk space and i resized the old one.

... Happy over all.

Comment: Hello. Answer is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that worked for me. I am on Elementary OS but i do believe is the same process. I installed the GNOME Disks where it could see all the available resized size but in another partition. Then on the first partition click the settings and then click resize:
[Resize partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDer5.png)

and expand to the size you want