# Vbox guest Ubuntu 18.04 not recognizing enlarged disk space

Tags: partitioning, mount, virtualbox, disk-management

The disk size was 40 gb then I started to get warnings of low space available so in host machine (windows 10) I ran `VBoxManage modifyhd "D:\vBoxDisks\Ubuntu Desktop 18.04\UbuntuDesktopBoxDisk.vdi" --resize 92160`

[image: see screenshot]

Then boot my Ubuntu guest and ran `lsblk -o name,size,type,fstype,mountpoint`

I got this (here im **putting only the last lines**):

```
sda                      40G disk             
└─sda1                   40G part LVM2_member 
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root      39G lvm  ext4        /
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1   976M lvm  swap        [SWAP]
sr0                    55,3M rom  iso9660     /media/kmms/VBox_GAs_5.2.18
```

Still showing the 40G instead of the new 90G.

What I need to do?

**Note: Im using a vbox snapshot but I rebooted the machine after the resizing**

Comment: i got a feeling that is something related with this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772279/guest-system-does-not-see-the-updated-disk-size-in-virtualbox#answer-773193)  (but im not sure)